# Hello World sample: "Something went wrong" when installing/testing

Tags: json, manifest, microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

I tried to get the example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-dotnet to run.
I successfully built and published (on Azure) the webapp.
Then I tried
 - manually editing the json file in the visual studio solution similarly to what the docs said, and then import the resulting zip in App Studio
 - adding the App directly in App Studio through the manifest editor (this works, but it fails when installing/testing it)

Both give me an error without any more info "something went wrong".

**Any way to actually figure out what I did wrong (if anything)?**

Either way, maybe you guys can figure it out from the json file's contents:

```
{
"$schema": "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.0/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.0",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": " 1CC58D17-1E95-443C-958F-E1F14D4CA3B4",
  "packageName": "com.contoso.helloworld",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Contoso",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/termsofuse"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Hello World",
    "full": "Hello World App for Microsoft Teams"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Hello World App for Microsoft Teams",
    "full": "This sample app provides a very simple app for Microsoft Teams. You can extend this to add more content and capabilities."
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "contoso20x20.png",
    "color": "contoso96x96.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#60A18E",
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "com.contoso.helloworld.hellotab",
      "name": "Hello Tab",
      "contentUrl": "https://microsoftteamssampleshelloworldweb20181022032046.azurewebsites.net/hello",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://microsoftteamssampleshelloworldweb20181022032046.azurewebsites.net/configure",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "needsChannelSelector": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "scopes": [
        "personal",
        "team"
      ],
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "getRandomText",
          "description": "Gets some random text and images that you can insert in messages for fun.",
          "title": "Get some random text for fun",
          "initialRun": true,
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "cardTitle",
              "description": "Card title to use",
              "title": "Card title"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [],
  "validDomains": []
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is a whitespace in your app Id in shared manifes:

```
"id": " 1CC58D17-1E95-443C-958F-E1F14D4CA3B4"
```

Could you please remove it and try and let us know if it works? Also you can remove bots and composeExtensions section if you want.

Comment: My goodness! It was actually that simple (the space in the App ID). Thank you very much. The original question still stands, though: I'm hoping App Studio has some way of telling me what went wrong, apart from posting it here :) ?

Comment: Blast! I was too quick to call this is as the solution. It resolved only the first step: I can now import the zip as a Team App. However, when I use "Test and Disribute" and then "Install", I still get a meaning less error: "Something went wrong, please try again later". Any more suggestions?

Comment: Could you please download the manifest and [Upload your package into a team using the Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/apps/apps-upload#upload-your-package-into-a-team-using-the-store)? Please let us know if you are getting any error there. I just tried your manifest (removing space) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet (not enough reputation points) but could you go through the instructions again?
I believe something went wrong with either the GUID, or one of the URL's. The instructions also advise to use ngrok, which is usefull for debugging.
If you can't find a clear error message, i advise you follow those instructions.

Comment: I tried a few times. I admit I'm taking a few shortcuts (the walkthrough makes me use the bot framework, which is not relevant to me now). I tried a few different GUIDs (but I'm guessing all GUIDs are created equal?) I also tried both importing the zip and the "manual" way. ngrok didn't work at the time because I could not reach the site for applying for an account. I was hoping App Studio would have some sort of logfile that I could look at to get more info? Or: is there another way (script?) to create/install/test a Teams app, that would give a usable error code?